# Key callbacks with gstreamer

Tags: c++, gstreamer

I was wondering if anyone has any idea of how to do key callbacks with gstreamer. I've looked, and can't find anything. I'm trying to do the equivalent of cvWaitKey. I do have OpenCV in my program and it can interact with Gstreamer. However, Gstreamer is outputting the video to the screen thus cvWaitKey doesn't work.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with GStreamer. Pick a UI toolkit like Gtk+ or Qt and use the functionality there.